# show that $\binom{p}{k}\equiv\frac{(-1)^{k-1}p}{k}\pmod {p^2}$

Tags: number-theory

Let $p$ be odd prime number,and for any postive integer $k$ show that
$$\binom{p}{k}\equiv\dfrac{(-1)^{k-1}p}{k}\pmod {p^2}$$

Comment: I think we need to assume $0<k<p$. Besides that, many users here tend to downvote so-called PSQs (Problem Statement Questions) like yours, and answers, too (some god will forgive them, but the poor human Jack won't). So it is in your (and community's) best interest to improve your actual question by adding some context (your attempts, why this question is relevant to you, something along these lines). Cheers.

Comment: Hint: $$\binom{p}{k}=\frac{p}{k}\cdot \frac{p-1}{1}\cdot\frac{p-2}{2}\cdot\ldots\cdot \frac{p-(k-1)}{k-1}=\frac{p}{k}(-1)^{k-1}\prod_{j=1}^{k-1}\left(1-\frac{p}{j}\right)$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

$$\prod_{r=1}^{k-1}(p-r)\equiv(-1)^{k-1}k!\pmod p$$

As for $1\le k\le p-1,(k!,p)=1$  divide both sides by $k!$

See property $\#12$ of   http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Congruence.html

Now multiply both sides by $p$